# R - ggplot geom_ribbon into apply function multiple plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, apply

I have a problem with my code. 
I have to print many plots in many pages in pdf and I have solved this with `apply` function and the `grid.Extra` package. 
My last problem (for now) is that I don't understand how it is possible to insert `geom_ribbon` inside the `apply` function because the columns are different.
I have tried in different ways. Starting from indices and then rebuild the `ymin` and `ymax` playing with `paste` and `gsub` commands. but this no good idea for resolving this problem.
here my code:

```
plotserieslines <- function(yvar){
  ggplot(d, aes_string(x=d$YEAR, y=yvar,  col = interaction(d$Manage, d$Meteo, sep="|"))) + geom_line( alpha=0.8)+
    geom_ribbon(aes_string(x= d$YEAR, ymin=yvar,ymax=yvar,fill = interaction(d$Manage, d$Meteo, sep="|")), alpha=0.1)+
       theme(legend.key=element_blank(),
          legend.background = element_blank(),
          legend.position = c(0.05, 0.95),
          axis.text=element_text(size=7),
          axis.title=element_text(size=7),
          legend.spacing.y = unit(-2.2, "cm"),
          legend.text=element_text(size=10),
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.7, 'lines')) +
    guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 1),
           fill=guide_legend( keywidth=0.4,
                              keyheight=0.2,
                              default.unit="cm")) +
    xlab("YEAR") +
    ylab(yvar)
  }
plots <- lapply(names(d[cod]), plotserieslines)

plots1 <-  marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow = 8, ncol = 5)
```

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of data with `dput` so we could reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think `purrr::map2()` can do the job.

```
plotserieslines2 <- function(yvar1, yvar2){
    ggplot(d) +
      geom_line(aes_string(x = "YEAR", y = yvar1, ...), ...) +
      geom_ribbon(aes_string(x = "YEAR", ymax = yvar1, ymin = yvar2, ...), ...) +
      ...
}

cols_ymax <- c("a_max", "b_max", "c_max")
cols_ymin <- c("a_min", "b_min", "c_min")
plots <- map2(cols_ymax, cols_ymin, plotserieslines2)
```

But, you should consider transforming the original data into ["tidy data"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) form by collapsing the columns into one column per `ymax` and `ymin`. Then, instead of `lapply()` or `map()`, you can use `facet_wrap()` like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

d <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  a_max = 1:3 * 10,
  b_max = 1:3 * 11,
  c_max = 1:3 * 12,
  a_min = 1:3 *  3,
  b_min = 1:3 *  4,
  c_min = 1:3 *  5
)

d
#>   id a_max b_max c_max a_min b_min c_min
#> 1  1    10    11    12     3     4     5
#> 2  2    20    22    24     6     8    10
#> 3  3    30    33    36     9    12    15

d_tidy <- d %>%
  gather("type", "value", -id) %>%
  separate(type, into = c("category", "min_or_max"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(min_or_max, value)

d_tidy
#>   id category max min
#> 1  1        a  10   3
#> 2  1        b  11   4
#> 3  1        c  12   5
#> 4  2        a  20   6
#> 5  2        b  22   8
#> 6  2        c  24  10
#> 7  3        a  30   9
#> 8  3        b  33  12
#> 9  3        c  36  15

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d_tidy) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(id, ymin = min, ymax = max)) +
  facet_wrap(~ category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!.
I have solved this issue using `mapply`  with the option `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` instead `lapply` and I have the possibility to use several argument for my function in easy way. With this function I obtain the same list of `lapply`.

The solution above is very good with `facet`, but I have hundreds of graphs that I want print in many pdf pages, and I don't know if `facet_grid` is the properly solution for multipage printing.
Anyway, thank you at all.

If there are other useful ways to overcome this problem in smarter ways, write in this post!   I have found poor informations about it and many solutions not works properly.

All the best!

Comment: Ah, It is a good reason not to use `facet`. Thanks for clarification :) One thing, as commented above, please consider including a sample of data with `dput()` next time, then it should be much easier to answer your question.